# RichTextBox select all text after Up- / Down-arrow

Tags: c#, richtextbox

I have a RichTextBox for which I have created a "scroll through sent messages" feature. This means that if the user sends (by pressing enter) any messages (up to 20), the user can then scroll through them in order by pressing the up/down arrows on the keyboard. This part works as intended.

The issue is: I want to select all text in the RichTextBox after each arrow press.

Here is my code:

```
    private void rtb_inputField_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
        RichTextBox inputField = (RichTextBox)sender;
        string userInput = inputField.Text.Trim();
        string[] clientScriptString = userInput.Split(' ');
        string modifiedInput = string.Empty;
        string macroString = string.Empty;

        //Other code...

        if (e.KeyData == Keys.Enter) {
                //Other code..

                if ((client != null) && (client.Connected)) {
                    macroString = runInputThroughMacroDictionary(userInput);
                    sendInputToServer(macroString);  //Sent message
                }


            addSentMessageToHistory(userInput);    //Added sent message to history
            e.Handled = true;
            e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
            hasUpBeenPressed = false;
        }

        if ((e.KeyData == Keys.Up) || (e.KeyData == Keys.Down)) {
            scrollThroughSentMessages(e);
            rtb_inputField.SelectAll();
        }
    }

    private void scrollThroughSentMessages(KeyEventArgs e) {
        if (sentMessageHistory.Count > 0) {
            if (e.KeyData == Keys.Up) {
                if (!hasUpBeenPressed) {
                    scrollThroughMsgHist = sentMessageHistory.Count - 1;
                }
                else {
                    scrollThroughMsgHist--;
                    if (scrollThroughMsgHist < 0) {
                        scrollThroughMsgHist = sentMessageHistory.Count - 1;
                    }
                }
                hasUpBeenPressed = true;
            }
            if ((e.KeyData == Keys.Down) && (hasUpBeenPressed)) {
                scrollThroughMsgHist++;
                if ((scrollThroughMsgHist >= 20) || (scrollThroughMsgHist > (sentMessageHistory.Count - 1))) {
                    scrollThroughMsgHist = 0;
                }
            }
            rtb_inputField.Text = sentMessageHistory[scrollThroughMsgHist];
        }
    }

    private void addSentMessageToHistory(string message) {
        int currentAmountOfMessage = sentMessageHistory.Count;

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(message)) {
            if (currentAmountOfMessage == 0) {
                sentMessageHistory.Add(message);
            }
            else {
                if (sentMessageHistory[currentAmountOfMessage - 1] != message) {
                    if (currentAmountOfMessage == 20) {
                        sentMessageHistory.RemoveAt(0);
                    }

                    sentMessageHistory.Add(message);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The first method does a whole bunch of things. (I removed some of the irrelevant code.) It adds the last sent message to sentMessageHistory (which is a List) via the third method. It also listens for Up/Down, and calls upon the second method.

The second method "scrolls through" each of the entries in the sentMessageHistory -List, and writes it in the RichTextBox. All of this works fine.

What doesn't work is the `rtb_inputField.SelectAll();` after the second method has run.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I added the following:

```
if ((e.KeyData == Keys.Up) || (e.KeyData == Keys.Down)) {
    scrollThroughSentMessages(e);
    e.Handled = true;
    e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
    rtb_inputField.SelectAll();
}
```

I don't know what `e.Handled` and `e.SupressKeyPress` does, but it works. So now my code successfully selects the text after "scrolling through history".